# How can I implement "Preview" in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, preview, transactionscope

Let's say I have a controller called `Pages`. In this controller, I have 3 actions: `Create`, `Edit`, `Details`.

In `Create` and `Edit`, in addition to the "Save" button, I want to have a "Preview" button, which loads `Details` in a new tab with the temporary data.

What's the best way to do that?

I thought about using `TransactionScope`, but how do I share it across multiple requests?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just send data by post to controller action, render new details view and post back the page without saving changes to the database. That should work as "preview". You can do this by  ajax as well to increase interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **jquery window** and post there your page's body by simple jquery **text()** function